How to initialize a prewritten function within a function?
I have 2 functions: one that opens a certain window with buttons, and the other one that does stuff that I need and closes a window.
It works fine if I defy second function within the first one, but I need them to be separate, and that's the problem.
If I separate them "newWindow" is undefined in "sleep" and therfore program doesn't work.
from re import I
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from array import *

def sleep(): # only closes a window for now
        newWindow.destroy()

def openNewWindow():
    
    # Toplevel object which will 
    # be treated as a new window
    newWindow = Toplevel()
 
    # sets the title of the
    # Toplevel widget
    newWindow.title("Action")
 
    # sets the geometry of toplevel
    newWindow.geometry("800x400")
        


    for r in range(6):
        btSle = Button(newWindow, text = "Sleep", command = sleep)

        
        btSle.grid(row = r, column = 1, sticky = W, pady = 2)



newWindow is local to openNewWindow() so undefined in sleep(). You could pass newWindow as an argument to the sleep function. See SO examples Link

Thanks, I'm still not sure how "lambda" and "command" operate, but slowly I'm getting there)

Have you tried adding a "global NewWindow"?
from re import I
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from array import *

def sleep():
    newWindow.destroy()
def openNewWindow():
    global newWindow # makes the variable visible to each function
    newWindow = Toplevel()
    newWindow.title("Action")
    newWindow.geometry("800x400")
    for r in range(6):
        btSle = Button(newWindow, text = "Sleep", command = sleep)
        btSle.grid(row = r, column = 1, sticky = W, pady = 2)

